File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 797, in _to_http_stream odoo-app |
Iam working on odoo community edition and deploying it using docker-compose but iam getting this error ,everytime
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/odoo/filestore/odoo2/d5/d5a961acdc563028ec787d266bc68c36f2d3fcd9'
odoo-app    | 2024-11-29 16:13:17,559 1 INFO odoo2 werkzeug: 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2024 16:13:17] "GET /web/assets/f6b89c1/web.assets_web.min.css HTTP/1.0" 500 - 3 0.001 0.004
odoo-app    | 2024-11-29 16:13:17,567 1 ERROR odoo2 odoo.http: Exception during request handling.
odoo-app    | Traceback (most recent call last):
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 2363, in __call__
odoo-app    |     response = request._serve_db()
odoo-app    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1891, in _serve_db
odoo-app    |     return self._transactioning(
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1954, in _transactioning
odoo-app    |     return service_model.retrying(func, env=self.env)
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 137, in retrying
odoo-app    |     result = func()
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1921, in _serve_ir_http
odoo-app    |     response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
odoo-app    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 2081, in dispatch
odoo-app    |     return self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 329, in _dispatch
odoo-app    |     result = endpoint(**request.params)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 727, in route_wrapper
odoo-app    |     result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/binary.py", line 149, in content_assets
odoo-app    |     stream = env['ir.binary']._get_stream_from(attachment, 'raw', filename)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_binary.py", line 125, in _get_stream_from
odoo-app    |     stream = self._record_to_stream(record, field_name)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_binary.py", line 72, in _record_to_stream
odoo-app    |     return record._to_http_stream()
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 797, in _to_http_stream
odoo-app    |     stat = os.stat(stream.path)
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/odoo/filestore/odoo2/7b/7b55d31b9a79e8320983384433d824527a234d27'
odoo-app    | 2024-11-29 16:13:17,568 1 INFO odoo2 werkzeug: 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2024 16:13:17] "GET /web/assets/0b7ece7/web.assets_web.min.js HTTP/1.0" 500 - 3 0.001 0.004
odoo-app    | 2024-11-29 16:13:17,706 1 ERROR odoo2 odoo.http: Exception during request handling.
odoo-app    | Traceback (most recent call last):
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 2363, in __call__
odoo-app    |     response = request._serve_db()
odoo-app    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1891, in _serve_db
odoo-app    |     return self._transactioning(
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1954, in _transactioning
odoo-app    |     return service_model.retrying(func, env=self.env)
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 137, in retrying
odoo-app    |     result = func()
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1921, in _serve_ir_http
odoo-app    |     response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
odoo-app    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 2081, in dispatch
odoo-app    |     return self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 329, in _dispatch
odoo-app    |     result = endpoint(**request.params)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 727, in route_wrapper
odoo-app    |     result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/binary.py", line 149, in content_assets
odoo-app    |     stream = env['ir.binary']._get_stream_from(attachment, 'raw', filename)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_binary.py", line 125, in _get_stream_from
odoo-app    |     stream = self._record_to_stream(record, field_name)
odoo-app    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_binary.py", line 72, in _record_to_stream
odoo-app    |     return record._to_http_stream()
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 797, in _to_http_stream
odoo-app    |     stat = os.stat(stream.path)
odoo-app    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
odoo-app    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/odoo/filestore/odoo2/21/213c2ad586882be5d30aac75259f07ee2b1c2c31'
odoo-app    | 2024-11-29 16:13:17,707 1 INFO odoo2 werkzeug: 172.18.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2024 16:13:17] "GET /web/assets/c9cd4e1/web.assets_web_print.min.css HTTP/1.0" 500 - 3 0.001 0.004

here is my docker-compose file :
version: '3.8'

services:
  # PostgreSQL database for Odoo
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: odoo-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: odoo3
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: odoo
      POSTGRES_DB: odoo
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app_network

  # Odoo 18 Community Edition
  odoo:
    image: odoo:18.0
    container_name: odoo-app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      HOST: postgres
      USER: odoo3
      PASSWORD: odoo
      PORT: 5432
      DB: odoo
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      # - ./odoo:/mnt/extra-addons 
      - ./odoo/odoo.conf:/etc/odoo/odoo.conf
      - ./odoo/addons:/mnt/addons
      - ./odoo/custom_addons:/mnt/custom_addons
    networks:
      - app_network

  # Next.js application
  nextjs:
    build:
      context: ./form
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nextjs-app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./form:/app  # Mount your form directory
    networks:
      - app_network

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  app_network:


below is my odoo.conf:
[options]
addons_path = /mnt/addons,/mnt/custom_addons
data_dir = /var/lib/odoo
admin_passwd = example@123

iam trying to resolve it from days
i have tried giving permission,then odoo -i base -d odoo --stop-after-init --db_host=db -r odoo -w odoo to reinit the db
then everything probably ,

I suppose you have tried several times "docker compose down" followed by "docker compose up -d". But this leaves the docker volume "postgres_data" untouched, so the DB is not cleaned up and this may cause an issue like this. Did you try with "docker compose down -v" which removes the volume, too?

yes i have manually deleted the containers using docker rm containerid

When you remove the containers ("docker compose down" is much easier), you should also remove the volume with "docker volume rm postgres_data". Otherwise the DB is not cleaned up.

You should change the services:odoo:volumes: of your docker-compose file:
services:
      odoo:
         volumes:
              - data:/var/lib/odoo

The DigitalOcean guide is good for standard installation (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-odoo-with-docker-on-ubuntu):
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  odoo:
    image: odoo:15.0
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/odoo
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

volumes:
  data:
  db:


OTHERWISE (if the modification described above does not solve your issue):
Because odoo installation has installed your filestore directory somewehere else (for example: ~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore ...)
You have to find the location of odoo2/21/213c2ad586882be5d30aac75259f07ee2b1c2c31 and copy it where odoo expects it:
docker cp filestore/.  /var/lib/odoo/filestore/


if the answer solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted
